TV cartoon or animated movie where the protagonist is a boy who drinks a red elixir potion from a glass jar with a cork to fight with giants
I watched it on VHS in early 1992-93. Most probably, it was an animated movie from an animated series or movie franchise.
In the film, a boy is the protagonist and the villains are giants. The boy drinks a red elixir potion from a glass jar with a cork to fight or engage with giants. The boy also has at least one girl with him, among a couple of companions.

What are the effects of the red potion on the boy? Does he become stronger / bigger / ...?

Regarding that part I am not sure. Most probably he becomes stronger & faster to match with giant.

Are the other companions human? Otherwise this sounds a lot like the Adventures of the Gummi Bears

Yes, hero has at least two three humans companion with him.
